# How to i update a column based on comparison with value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-update, subquery

I crated a script to update a column based on the result of comparison betwen values in two tables.This script works when i created copies of these tables somewhere else but it updates zero values when i applied it on the live system

I have two tables `C1` and `C2`.Table `C2` has some columns includind  a column called `EXIT_DATE` which i need to compare with a column called `RECEIPTDATE` in table `C1` where `MEMBER_NUMBERS` match and `EXIT_DATE` is greater than `RECEIPTDATE`. When the condition is met then i need to set a column `USED` in table `C1` to `Y`.

```
UPDATE  SS_CONTRIBUTIONS c1
set C1.USED = 'Y'
 where SCHEME_ID = 1 and rowid <
     (
      select max(rowid)
        from SS_BENEFIT c2
       where c2.MEMBERID= c1.MEMBER_ID
       and c2.EXIT_DATE > c1.RECEIPTDATE
       );commit;
```

i expect 350000 records to be updated but it updates 0 record

Answer (score 3):

I would advocate againts using `rowid` here. This pseudo-column represents the *address* of the row (object number, data block, ...), and I cannot see how it would be useful for what you are trying to accomplish.

I think that a correlated subquery should work just fine for your use case:

```
update ss_contributions c1 
set c1.used = 'Y' 
where 
    c1.scheme_id = 1
    and c1.receiptdate < (
        select max(c2.exit_date)
        from ss_benefit c2 
        where c2.memberid= c1.member_id
    );
```

Comment: you forgot `SCHEME_ID = 1`

Comment: also your `and` operator :)

Comment: @GMB . . . `rowid` is just wrong.  It makes sense (sometimes) when comparing rows within a single table.  It does not make sense for cross table comparisons.

Comment: Thanx.This works fine if a want to perfom a comparison for the whole.I have another case where i now want to compare and update  for a specific number.I modied the script to